# Datatable - date sorting dd/mm/yyyy - works in demo but not in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, datatables

In my rails app, I'm using datatables, works well. But, I can't sortable columns dd/mm/yyyy.
So, I search in foruns and I found the solution.

I tested in this [**demo**](http://live.datatables.net/ASAV/4/edit).

In case, the important is sort the first column respecting the date formart: dd/mm/yyyy.

But the solution its not working in my app.
I copied and cut the same code in my file javascript and a table.

interns.js

```
$(document).ready( function () {
 $('#hr_curriculum_interns').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType": "date-uk" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
  });  
} );


jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
  var ukDatea = a.split('/');
  return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
},

"date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
   return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
},

"date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
   return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
} );
```

application.js

```
...
//= require interns
...
```

/views/_table_hr_curriculum_interns.html.erb

```
    <div class="container">
      <table id="hr_curriculum_interns" class="table table-striped" data-source="<%= hr_curriculum_interns_url(format: "json") %>">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Age</th>
             <th>Position</th>
             <th>-</th>
             <th>-</th>
             <th>-</th>
             <th>-</th>
             <th>-</th>
             <th>-</th>
             <th>-</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>


       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>01/01/1985</td>
           <td>Athos</td>   
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>    
        </tr>

         <tr>
           <td>01/01/1980</td>
           <td>Athos</td>   
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>    
        </tr> 

         <tr>
           <td>02/01/1981</td>
           <td>Athos</td>   
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>  
           <td>Athos</td>    
        </tr> 

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.ui.tabs
//= require jquery.ui.tabs.min
//= require bootstrap-tabs
//= require interns
//= require systems_analysts
//= require generics
//= require vacancies
//= require file_field
//= require bootstrap-filestyle
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

All columns, unless the first, could be sortable.
When a click in firts column, not happens. =/

Ps: Sorry for my english

Ps2: This is a test, I will to use datas from my database

Comment: Using `dd/mm/yyyy` is fine when you want to display a date, but it is not really helpful for a machine. Use a descending-significance format to sort them, e.g. the _ISO_ `yyyy-MM-dd` or even their ms-since-unix-epoch value.

Comment: Yeap, but I need show the data in brazilian format, in my database, the format is yyyy-MM-dd, in this case, the plugin datatable is only  sorting in client side, I guess with this not make differences for the machine, or not?

Comment: Your sort algorithm works fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/dup75/ so this is a ruby problem.

Comment: Do you have "//= require jquery" in application.js (before require interns)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, yes, I do. In my table in rails app, I can to sort all columns correctly, less the first

Comment: @ivalkeen, you give me the solution, haha, in application.js, I put //= require interns after //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap, works now, thanks a lot =]